# How to inflate custom view with XML layout with use of ViewBinding?

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-custom-view, android-viewbinding

I have layout in XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/hsv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="92dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#555555"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

And extended `HorizontalScrollView` as custom view definition:

```kotlin
class TopBubblesWidget(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null) : HorizontalScrollView(context, attrs) {
    private var binding: FragmentBiometricTopBubblesBinding = FragmentBiometricTopBubblesBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context))
    private var data: List<BubblesWidget.Data>? = null

    override fun onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate()
        binding.rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
    }

    private fun initView(data: List<BubblesWidget.Data>) {
        binding.rv.adapter = TopBubblesAdapter(data)
    }

    fun updateData(data: List<BubblesWidget.Data>) {
        initView(data)
    }
}
```

The problem is that `TopBubblesWidget` is not inflated by the XML and I do not see the RecyclerView.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I am not sure what you're trying to achieve here? What's the layout of your custom view? If the layout mentioned in the question is the one then your view shouldn't be extending `HorizontalScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling this is what you are looking for. This is a sample code -

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PartyViewHolder {
    return PartyViewHolder(
        PartyListItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)),
        viewModel
    )
}
```

---

and if you want to inflate a custom view like a prompt, here's a sample code -

```
private fun logOutAndExit() {
    val dialogBox = Dialog(requireContext())
    val promptLogOutBinding = PromptLogOutBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)//declaration done here
    dialogBox.apply {
            setContentView(promptLogOutBinding.root)
            window!!.setLayout(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            )
            setCancelable(false)
            show()
        }
```

in the top, my layout file is `party_list_item` while, in the bottom example, my layout is `prompt_log_out`

and this -

```
PartyListItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context))
```

is how you inflate a custom layout